# Confused about recursion and how to make return print

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

This is my homework to start with. But as I've read before on this site people tell you to try it out first. I have now tried to understand recursion but I'm just not getting it. I was thinking if someone could help me with this one so I could get a grasp about the whole concept and then solve the rest of my homework.

So the idea in this is that the user inputs how many layers of cans there is in a pyramid. With that info the program should be able to calculate how many cans there is in the whole pyramid. Layers go 1 - 4 - 9 - 16 and so on.

As I said before I am not expecting someone to write me the code, I really wanna understand recursion.

```
def cans(layers):
    if layers == 0:
       return 1
    else:
       return layers * cans(layers-1)

layers = raw_input("How many layers are there?: ")
print cans
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the point of the recursion here. For each layer, the calculation is simple - it's just the square of the layer's number. However, to calculate the number of cans in the **entire** pyramid, you can use recursion.

Here's a way to think about it:

- How many cans are there in a pyramid with N layers? N<sup>2</sup> plus the number of cans in a pyramid with N-1 layers.
- So how many cans are there in a pyramid with N-1 layers? (N-1)<sup>2</sup> plus the number of cans in a pyramid with N-2 layers.
- So how many cans are there in a pyramid with N-2 layers? (N-2)<sup>2</sup> plus the number of cans in a pyramid with N-3 layers.
- And so on ... until you reach your end-condition, which could be an empty pyramid (a pyramid with 0 layers).

If we express the same logic in python:

```
def cans(layers):
    if layers == 0:
       return 0
    else:
       return layers**2 + cans(layers-1)
```

Comment: Okay so the else is the one which counts the cans and if layers == 0: stops the counting right? I added layers = input("How many layers are there? ") but python doesn't return anything?

Comment: @benitso yup, you got the gist of it. Note you should be printing `cans(layers)` and not just `cans` as your question currently shows. If this isn't the issue, please edit your post with the current code, and let's see what went wrong there

Comment: It worked when I printed cans(layers) . I've been trying to understand recursion for months now and you made me realise/understand (hopefully) what it's all about in mere 2-3 hours. Thank you sir! I was so close to giving up with learning Python, thank you!